# nmake и автоматические зависимости

Tags: visual-c++, makefile

makefile для **nmake**, не для gnu.

Записано правило `.cpp.obj:`, все нормально, все хорошо. Не считая того, что если я меняю `.h`-файл, то `nmake` не понимает, что надо перекомпилировать соответствующие .cpp-файлы, которые от него зависят.

Конечно, можно решить вопрос, руками прописав вместо одного `.cpp.obj:` массу правил с зависимостями для каждого файла, но это жутко неудобно и резко увеличивает запутанность и размер файла. Есть ли какой-то способ покрасивее?

Comment: ¿Если не хотите вручную прописывать зависимости, то зачем использовать make?

Comment: @user7860670 Потому что файлов в проекте много. И писать для каждого зависимости тяжело. В свое время в Ваткоме была команда .autodepend, очень помогала.

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, что Вам подойдёт вот это:

> Using Targets in Multiple Description Blocks
> A target can appear in only one description block when specified using the single-colon (:) syntax to separate the target from the dependent.
> To update a target using more than one description block, specify two consecutive colons (::) between targets and dependents. One use for this feature is for building a complex target that contains components created with
> different commands.
> Example
> The following makefile updates a library:
>
> ```nmake
> target.lib :: one.asm two.asm three.asm  
>             ML one.asm two.asm three.asm
>             LIB target -+one.obj -+two.obj -+three.obj;   
> target.lib :: four.c five.c  
>             CL /c four.c five.c LIB target -+four.obj -+five.obj;
> ```
>
> If any of the assembly-language files have changed more recently than the
> library, NMAKE assembles the source files and updates the library.
> Similarly, if any of the C-language files have changed, NMAKE compiles
> the C files and updates the library.

Смысл этого в том, что при измении любого из файлов зависимости, будут автоматически выполненые команды для данных целей с обновлением библиотек.

Comment: Вопрос вроде как был про то, как избежать прописывания зависимостей вручную.

Comment: Программа делает только то, что ей скажут. Соответственно, без указания «целей» и «зависимостей» никуда не уйти. Данный же способ позволяет сократить количество этих самых «целей» и «зависимостей». Ну и вообще‐то лучше увидеть этот самый make-файл.